# ¿Como se soluciona el problema de visualización de un proyecto de Laravel que no muestra?

Tags: laravel

¡Buenas noches!; realice un proyecto en Laravel que se llama "proyectolaravel"; que para ello primeramente instale el xampp la ultima versión, y luego de para instalar el laravel seguí los pasos que esta en la documentación de Laravel en el siguiente link:

[Instalación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7)

y luego utilice la plantilla coreui para mi proyecto de laravel, y luego realice la compilación de las librerías css y js de acuerdo al manual de laravel

[Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix)

Por lo que de acuerdo a este link realice la instalación de Laravel mix que para ellos instale node.js y para verificar desde el terminal de visual studio code puse node -v y npm -v; si no instalado el lavarel mix desde la misma terminal de comandos puse npm install que se instala el lavarel mix; una vez especificado las librerias /css y /ls en la carpeta de proyecto /resources/plantilla/css (las librerias css) y /resources/plantilla/js (las librerias js), pero al compilarlo con npm run dev me sale correctamente, que adjunto pantalla

[image: Compilación de las librerias css y js]

y desde la misma terminal de comandos de Visual Studio para correr el proyecto lavarel desde la ventana de esta manera php artisan serve, que me obtiene la dirección que hay que poner en el navegador pero al ejecutar no sale nada y sale una pantalla en blanco, no lo se si haya que configurar algo en el programa xampps (en la configuración del apache) para que pueda correr bien, o alguna configuración ya que me sale una pantalla en blanco y no aparece la ejecución de mi proyecto en laravel, adjunto pantalla:

[image: Problema al ejecutar el proyecto de Laravel]

Estoy trabajando mi proyecto de laravel en una computadora Laptoop marca Lenovo con Windows 7 de 64 bits Ultimate, su ayuda con esto que no muestra ya que anteriormente si mostraba proyecto, adjunto pantalla que mostraba antes que ahora no muestra:

[image: Proyecto de Laravel que se mostraba antes sin problemas]

Comment: Todos estos problemas casi que no existen usando docker o homestead.

Comment: @Shaz estimado buenos días!; ¿como hago para que funcionr este si hay que instalar docker o homestead?; ya que anteriormente una vez desde el xampo al correr el apache y mysql pero anteriormente al poner http://127.0.0.1:8000 si me corria el proyecto como el que te puse en la muestra

Comment: @Shaz una consulta ¿Existe otra manera de ejecutar mi proyecto laravel que no sea lo que me dices?; ya que anteriormente si me presentaba mi proyecto en laravel que se llama "proyectolaravel" poniendo en la barra de dirección del navegador http://127.0.0.1:8000 y cargaba sin problemas mi proyecto en Laravel

Comment: Hay muchísimas formas, una búsqueda en google te arroja todas las posibilidades que hay. Personalmente prefiero usar docker, homestead o en el peor de los casos `php artisan serve`.

Comment: @Shaz estimado buenas tardes!; te saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone desde Ecuador te doy ¡Gracias!, por tu respuesta pero solo querría saber si ¿en el xampp hay que configurar el apache y mysql los 2 servicio para que cargue el proyecto de Lavarel sin problemas?; te pido a ver si me puedes apoyar con esto y te agradezco tu ayuda o sino algún amigo tuyo que tenga cuenta en esta página que sepa de Laravel me pueda ayudar con esto que no corre mi proyecto de Laravel o pasame un link donde puedo buscar mas informacion y ayuda de esto.

Comment: Conozco muy bien Laravel, pero nunca lo he utilizado con xampp porque lo considero una pésima herramienta para el desarrollo web.